# web scraping from challenging source with node.js and puppeteer

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I would like to web scrape dance center timetable. At this moment I have almost all required informations apart of start time and duration of classes and I have no idea how to get this data:

[image]

Directed link: https://loftodance.pl/grafik

I use node.js + puppeteer. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Use Chrome Dev Tools. Inspect the element.

Right-click on the element in Dev Tools > Copy > Copy XPath

Then use puppeteer's `page.$x()`

```
page.$x("//*[@id="scroll-hours-1-1"]/div[5]");
```